# AEM: getting error on restarting AEM SDK not able to access any screens

Tags: aem

HTTP ERROR 503 AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate request.
URI:    /
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate request.
SERVLET:    org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet-36d9ed7f

AEM SDK: aem-sdk-2022.1.6228.20220123T154100Z-211100

Getting above error every time after restarting AEM SDK server in local environment. Till now I am  just deleting quick start folder and restart local server. But I need a permanent solution for this. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: How are you shutting down the instance?

Comment: If this is the issue I think it is, I believe it’s fixed in latest SDK. Refer to this: https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-servlets-resolver/pull/23

Comment: @ronnyfm im shutting it down by clicking on off botton present on AEM quick start. Im getting same error even if I start instance using java -jar <aem-instance>

Comment: @AhmedMusallam im using latest sdk aem-sdk-2022.1.6228.20220123T154100Z-211100

Comment: And are you using a JDK or JRE?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?